# Unrationalize Denominator

Tags: fractions, rationalising-denominator

What is the method to unrationalize or reverse a rationalized fraction?

**For example:**  How do you simplify $\frac{1}{2\sqrt\frac{1}{2}}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Now you can multiply by "1":
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{2})^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$